# histfit seems to be modifying graph data

Tags: matlab, statistics, histogram, data-analysis, matlab-guide

I am looking to plot my data in MATLAB as a histogram with a normal distribution line drawn. I have used the `histfit` function but I do not understand why the graphs do not seem to match? e.g. the data no longer goes above 300.

Could someone explain why the values seem to be changing when using this function?

[image: graph]

Comment: Same number of bins ?

Comment: I'm not specifying either way, I assumed they would use the same number?

Comment: It looks like there is more bins on the right histogram, so you should explicitly specify the number of bins. (btw, the normal distribution don't seems to fit your data in this case)

Comment: That ended up being the issue, thanks! If you want to put your comment as an answer I'll accept.